# Pear Mail Queue - logs/records?

Tags: php, email, pear

I am using Pear Mailer and the Mail Queue to send emails. Is it possible to keep the record of each mail in the mail_queue table rather than it being deleted as soon as it is sent?

It would be useful to track the mail for debugging.

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section "Utilising Callbacks for Report Generation" on http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-queue.mail-queue.tutorial.php.
All you have to do is (copy it and) implement the function `insert_to_log` to write the data in a separate log table.

Comment: Thanks rik, do you know where the function is called?